# How can I use or represent special characters like \ and { inside \csname...\endcsname?

Tags: macros, symbols

I want to `\def` a macro with a name that represents arbitrary string data, including the `\`, `{` and `}` characters. My initial approach was to use `\textbackslash` and `\{` to test that I could do this. But they can't be used in `\csname...\endcsname`, as shown here. What would be an alternative approach? Are there alternatives to `\textbackslash` and `\{` that could be used in `\csname...\endcsname`?

It isn't any good to just temporarily redefine `\textbackslash` and `\{` to `\empty`. The macro name generated has to be different for the string `text\{moretext` than it is for the string `textmoretext`. Whatever macro is used has to meaningfully represent the fact that a certain specific character occurs at that position in the string/macro name, in order to avoid collisions with other macro names so generated.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
**\relax
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.

*\expandafter\def\csname some text \textbackslash some more text\endcsname{}
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \global
<*> ...ndafter\def\csname some text \textbackslash
                                                   some more text\endcsname{}
?

*\expandafter\def\csname some text \{ some more text\endcsname{}
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \protect
<*> \expandafter\def\csname some text \{
                                         some more text\endcsname{}
?

*
```

Comment: There are three interesting and thought-provoking answers here. I'm going to have to examine and think about each one tomorrow in order to work out which one gives me what I need (maybe more than one of them does).

Comment: Rember what _The TeXbook_ says on page 40, line 15 (cf. @egreg’s answer).

Comment: I don't know what it says.

Comment: That the characters token between `\csname` and `\endcsname` “can be of any category code, not necessarily letters”.  Example: `\csname {}$& #^_ a?\endcsname`.  Nonetheless, of course, you cannot have active characters (they are expanded), comment characters, invalid characters…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't plan to have unbalanced braces inside `\csname...\endcsname` when you use it in the argument to anothe command, you can directly use `{` and `}`. For the backslash, just use `\string`; the only problem is to persuade TeX not to gobble a space after the mock control sequence:

```
\expandafter\def\csname some text\string\some\space more} text\endcsname{}
```

will work. If you want to be on the safe side, use `\@charlb` for the left brace and `\@charrb` for the right brace and define

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup\escapechar=-1
\xdef\@charbs{\string\\}
\endgroup
\makeatother
```

If you don't want `@`-commands, just define equivalents:

```
\makeatletter
\let\charlb=\@charlb
\let\charrb=\@charrb
\begingroup\escapechar=-1
\xdef\@charbs{\string\\}
\endgroup
\let\charbs=\@charbs
\makeatother
```

Then

```
\expandafter\def\csname some text\charbs some more\charrb\space text\endcsname{}
```

would do the same as before.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Thanks. You know, when there's a competing answer which lacks knowledge…

Answer (score 5):

```
\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\csname xx\expandafter\@gobble\string\{yy\endcsname{}
\expandafter\show\csname xx\expandafter\@gobble\string\{yy\endcsname
```

Answer (score 4):

e-TeX's `\detokenize` helps to convert an arbitrary argument to something, which is safe to be used inside `\csname`:

```
\expandafter\def\csname\detokenize{some text \foo{hello} \bar some more text}\endcsname{}
```

Comment: But that would put the control sequence’s name `\textbackslash`, and _not_ a backslash, inside the name being `\def`ined.

Comment: Note, however, that `\detokenize` adds a space after `\foo` which may be unwanted.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti The question is not too clear, I have just taken "arbitrary string data, including the ``\``, `{` and `}` characters" literally. Using `\detokenize`, it is not necessary to convert these characters to macros, which prints itself.

Comment: I was wondering whether I had just dreamt about `\textbackslash`, or what.  But I agree that mention of `\detokenize` is pertinent to the question (I was about to suggest it myself ;-) .

Comment: @egreg: The question is not too clear. My understanding was, that different strings need to be different, whatever string means.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti The very first version of my answer contained `\textbackslash`, which I have removed to avoid confusion. The edit was inside the five minute window, thus no revision is made.

Comment: Yes, I guessed that!  Note, however, that, as @egreg says, `\expandafter\def\csname Some text with strange characters:{}$& #^_ Stop\endcsname{}` works fine.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti It depends on the category codes.

Comment: However, on second thought, characters bearing a category code that causes them to disappear during the reading phase, like comment and end-of-line characters, cannot even reach `\detokenize`.